# Include google pub on the website

Tags: php, html, adsense, adsense-api

I have a question, I tried to include a pub in my website. I look in console and I have no errors but the pub is not displayed. My code :

```
 <div class="right-bloc-pub-1">
                <script type="text/javascript" async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                     style="display:block;"
                     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890234567"
                     data-ad-slot="73467345"
                     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
                <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                </script>
            </div>
```

Can you help me please? Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting js code to window load function

```
window.onload = function () {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
}
```

---

Also make sure:
 - You have disabled your AdBlocker, if any (`disable everywhere`, not only for `disable on ...`
- You have set width and height for your Ad. Inspect iFrame `<body>` if it's empty or not.
- If your account previous was rejected, there must pass around 24h for Google to pass content to your requests after account verification. You must receive email with title `Your Google AdSense account has been fully activated`.
- Make sure your account is not banned.

I had same issue (waited around 1 day for ads to appear on website). You can check implementation in my site http://www.justinas.tk (one white block above footer). If you view source, will see that code is identical you yours.